# How can I get away with this weird space?

Tags: html, css

I'm totally beginner, but I really don't know why there is a space between the bottom of my image and my wrap div border!

What's this???

```
<div class="myItem">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
</div>

.myItem {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    background: tomato;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g7rvm0ub/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:block` to `img` will remove the bottom space, another approach is add `vertical-align:middle` to `img`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the div is 5 pixels bigger than the the image, as I am a bit of a beginner as well, but one way to fix it is to decrease the size of the div using `height: 100px`.